# Sharepoint 2010 , Circular file references are not allowed

Tags: 2010, page-layout

after changing the page layout of some pages,
I got `Circular file references are not allowed.`

Note : The site was upgraded from 2007.

The last Exception in the stack trace is : 
`Microsoft.sharepoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependecies( HttpContext context, SPRequest...`

Answer (score 1):

can you check this out, it will explain the error for you :)

> When you try to run a Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Web application that is
>   built on the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, you may receive an error
>   message that resembles one of the following error messages:
>
> The base class includes the field 'MyControl_1', but its type
>   (MyControl) is not compatible with the type of control
>   (ASP.MyControl_ascx).
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.MyControl_ascx' to type
>   'MyNameSpace.MyControl '.
>
> Circular file references are not allowed.  **Note:** In these error
>   messages, MyControl is the name of the control that has caused the
>   error. MyNameSpace is the name of the namespace that this control is a
>   member of
>
> This is problem occurs because of the way in which ASP.NET 2.0 uses
>   the application references and the folder structure of the application
>   to compile the application. If the batch property of the 
>   element in the web.config file for the application is set to true,
>   ASP.NET 2.0 compiles each folder in the application into a separate
>   assembly. In this scenario, a circular reference may occur.
>   Additionally, the compilation process may fail if either of the
>   following conditions is true:
>   •The application contains references to
>   Web controls.
>
> •The application contains references to Web pages that are outside the
>   current directory.
>
> **To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods:**
>
> **Method 1:** Modify the web.config file To modify the web.config file,
>   set the batch property of the  element in the web.config
>   file for the application to false.
>
> Note This method is recommended only for small applications. In large
>   production applications, when you set the batch property to false,
>   ASP.NET 2.0 compiles each page in the application into a separate
>   assembly. The individual page assemblies are then loaded at the next
>   available memory location. Additionally, the individual page
>   assemblies cannot be moved. This causes memory fragmentation.
>
> **Method 2:** Reorder the folders in the application To avoid a circular
>   reference, reorder the folders in the application. To reorder these
>   folders, follow these steps:
>
> 1.Trace the references to the file and
>   from the file that is indicated by the error message.
>
> 2.Identify the circular reference.
>
> 3.To avoid the circular reference, put the referenced files together in the same folder.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919284

without code and full error I and others cant really help!

hope it helps :)